# Como crear alerta cuando TextBox esta vacio antes de hacer clic en boton guardar - C# visual estudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, validación, textbox

Un saludo a todos, les agradezco de antemano, espero puedan ayudarme soy nuevo y autodidacta en c#; tengo el siguiente problema: Intento alertar al usuario cuando un "TextBox" se encuentra vacio y cancelar el proceso de guardar, en los campos donde los que se ingresa se almacena con tipo de dato "String" no e tenido problema:
`if (obj.Nombre == "") { Mensaje += "Es necesario el nombre del Producto\n"; }`
pero no e tenido exito con los campos donde lo que se ingresa se almacenara con tipo de dato "Int" :

```
if (obj.Stock == '0')
        {
            Mensaje += "Es necesario el stock del Producto\n";
        }
```

Si la condicion del "TextBox" Stcock es "vacio", para confirmar esto lo debo comparar con con "0" ? eso seria lo correcto ? ya que "obj.Stock" es de tipo entero:

```
 public class Producto
{
    public int IdProducto { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public Categoria oCategoria { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public decimal PrecioCompra { get; set; }
    public decimal PrecioVenta { get; set; }
    public bool Estado { get; set; }
    public string FechaRegistro { get; set; }
}
```

Al ejecutar el codigo simulando el campo Stock vacio; Visual Estudio me arrroja este error "System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'" en el evento del Boton Guardar:

```
Producto obj = new Producto()
        {
            IdProducto = Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text),
            Codigo = txtcodigo.Text,
            Nombre = txtnombre.Text,
            Descripcion = txtdescripcion.Text,
            
            oCategoria = new Categoria() { IdCategoria = Convert.ToInt32(((OpcionCombo)cbocategoria.SelectedItem).Valor) },
            Stock = Convert.ToInt32(txtstock.Text),
            PrecioCompra = Convert.ToDecimal(txtpreciocompra.Text),
            PrecioVenta = Convert.ToDecimal(txtprecioventa.Text),


            Estado = Convert.ToInt32(((OpcionCombo)cboestado.SelectedItem).Valor) == 1 ? true : false
           
            //PrecioCompra = txtpreciocompra.
            //PrecioVenta = txtprecioventa.
        };
```

A diferencia de "obj.Nombre" que es de tipo String y en el cual si se logra el objetivo de alertar que el campo esta vacio y detener el proceso de "guardar".

[Obj.nombre resultado exitoso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htFrX.jpg)

[image: Error al ejecutar codigo con TextBox "Stock" vacio]

Comment: En el textbox, todo es un texto.. no hay numeros ni otra cosa.. despues los podes transformar, eso si.. proba cono int.tryparse...

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion pero la pregunta sigue sin tener el tag de C#

Answer (score 0):

`Stock = Convert.ToInt32(txtstock.Text)` primero resolverá `Convert.ToInt32(txtstock.Text)` y después de resuelto le asignara el valor a `Stock`, pero en el primer paso `(Convert.ToInt32(txtstock.Text)` ya tendras un error porque `Convert.ToInt32` no puede convertir un valor vacío en numero, entiendes?

Debes utilizar una instrucción de "test" como `Tryparse` primero y asegurarte de que el valor del `textbox` si es posible convertir en numero y DESPUES asignarlo.

Te dejo un ejemplo con lambdas.

```
int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue) ? 0 : stringValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar que un texto está vacío puedes usar esta condición:

```
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtstock.Text))
    {
        mensaje += "Debe ingresar un valor en el campo Stock";
    }
```

Para verificar que ingresen un valor numérico, puedes usar esta condición:

```
    int stock;
    int.TryParse(txtstock.Text, out stock);
    
    if(stock <= 0) 
    {
        mensaje += "Debe ingresar un valor numérico en Stock";
    }
```